# Parent jenkins job to be cloned for every fork of that git repo

Tags: git, jenkins

Can we have a parent jenkins job (gets triggered for every commit happening with the web hooked git repo) to be cloned for every fork of that git repo.

More Details:

1. I have a git repo and i have a jenkins job hooked to it.
2. For every commit, the jenkins job gets triggered.
3. Now the question - If someone fork the git repo, I need the jenkins job also to be cloned. How to achieve this.

Comment: Can you specify why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have a pipeline built and if others want to use this, a simple fork of the repo should be able to provide the pipeline. Ofcouse, they can manually clone the jenkins job. I am trying to find if anything else is possible.

Comment: why don't you use branches instead of forks?

Comment: As @SudhirR noted, this would be much easier. In such case you might create a hook on new origin which you would get from git/gitlab, etc. That might put a job into the queue processed by the same node.

Comment: You can do that with the Generic Webhook trigger and a Jenkins2 pipeline. Here's a sample pipeline that create a job programmatically - https://github.com/wso2/testgrid-jenkins-library/blob/dev/vars/JobCreatorPipeline.groovy#L205-L265 I can provide more details if interested.

Comment: Awesome Kasun. This would help me. Please share further details if any. Thanks.

Comment: @SudhirR - I dont want to create branches.